# Shared disk among libvirt VM

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt

So, I am trying to share a disk between two libvirt VMs. I created a disk using `qemu-img create` and then used `virsh attach-disk` to attach that disk to a VM. Now, I want to attach the same disk to another VM as well. When I try to attach to next VM, I get the following error:

```
error: Failed to attach disk
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'device_add': Failed to get "write" lock
```

Is that possible? If not, is there any other better alternative? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All hard disks are setup for exclusive access by default, with only CDROM media being allowed to be shared by multiple VMs. To override this default behaviour you need to set the `<shareable/>` element within the `<disk>...</disk>` config. There is further documentation about disk setup at https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsDisks

The shareable flag causes the SELinux/AppArmor policy to allow shared access, and tells the libvirt & QEMU lock managers to use shared locks.

NB, this only works for disks backed by raw volumes. You can never use a qcow2 image for a shared-write disk as it will cause corruption of the qcow2 metadata.